# Image disappear when click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I just want to know the reason why the image disappears after I close the lightbox?

http://campbrand.myshopify.com/blogs/good-company/47835523-donec-pede-justo-fringilla-vel-aliquet-nec#

password: chough

Comment: What lightbox are you talking about? Please paste relevant code snippets rather than granting access to a website.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using correctly fancybox, you page throws "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fancybox is not a function". Also review this code you have:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
```

change it for:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
```

also $("a.zoom") is empty